# Como gerar programa executável .jar no NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Fiz uma aplicação em Java e gostei, agora preciso de obter executável para mostrar aos meus colegas.

Como faço para obter o executável?

Comment: Elton, só para ficar claro: quando diz executável se refere a um arquivo `.JAR` ou um arquivo `.EXE`  ?

Answer (score 9):

Qual IDE está utilizando?

Se for o NetBeans é só clicar com o botão direito em cima do projeto e ir em "Limpar e Construir", então a IDE irá criar uma pasta no diretório do projeto chamada "dist" contendo seu arquivo .jar e uma pasta chamada "lib" contendo as bibliotecas utilizadas no projeto.

Comment: É evidente na questão que a IDE é o netbeans.

Comment: Desculpa pela desatenção. Mas de qualquer maneira o procedimento é o que descrevi.

Answer (score 1):

Como respondeu o Anderson, basta clicar com o botão direito e clicar em "Limpar e Construir" não esqueça que para rodar aplicações .jar, você precisa do JRE Instalado, que contem a máquina virtual para interpretação do file .jar !

Comment: Na verdade o que é necessário é o JRE, o JDK é voltado para os desenvolvedores. Junto com a instalação do JDK já vem a do JRE junto, mas daí o usuário estará instalando uma ferramenta a mais desnecessariamente (o JDK).

Comment: Erro meu, obrigado @Math ! =]