# Criar um executavel de uma aplicação Java

Tags: java, jar

Fiz uma aplicação que possui um timer para olhar em determinado diretório de 2 em 2 segundos, bom quando estou executando a aplicação no NetBeans ela funciona normalmente, porém tentei criar um JAR desta aplicação e ele não fica executando no gerenciador de aplicações, se tiverem alguma ideia de o que pode estar acontecendo ou como criar um executável desta aplicação quem sabe.

Grato

```
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="IMPORTAÇÕES">
//import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.ini4j.Ini;
import org.ini4j.IniPreferences;
import org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException;
//</editor-fold>

public class LeituraPDF_Filtro_Validacao_FINAL_02 {

    public static final long TEMPO = (25 * 60); // TIMER DE REPETIÇÃO DA APLICAÇÃO

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InvalidFileFormatException, IOException {

        System.out.println("inicio");
        Timer timer = null;
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="CARRREGAR ARQUIVO *.INI DE CONFIGURAÇÕES DE CAMINHOS DE ACESSO">
                        Ini ini = new Ini(new File("C:\\Embratec_Slips\\Em Processamento\\configHSS.ini"));
                        java.util.prefs.Preferences prefs = new IniPreferences(ini);
                        String inPath = prefs.node("cfg").get("inPath", "null").split(";")[0].trim();
                        String outPath = prefs.node("cfg").get("outPath", "null").split(";")[0].trim();
                        String inProcess = prefs.node("cfg").get("inProcess", "null").split(";")[0].trim();
                        //</editor-fold>

                        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="DIRETÓRIO DOS ARQUIVOS *.PDF">
                        File diretorio = new File(inProcess);
                        File[] arquivos = diretorio.listFiles();
                        //</editor-fold>

                        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="VERIFICAR SE HÁ ARQUIVOS NO DIRETÓRIO DESCRITO">
                        if (arquivos != null) {

                            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="VERIFICAR TODOS OS ARQUIVOS NO DIRETÓRIO">
                            for (int x = 0; x < arquivos.length; x++) {

                                //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="ABRIR TODOS OS ARQUIVOS *.PDF DO DIRETÓRIO">
                                if (arquivos[x].getName().endsWith("pdf")) {

                                    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="ABRIR ARQUIVO *.PDF">
                                    File f = arquivos[x];
                                    try (RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream acesso = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath())) {
                                        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(acesso);
                                        parser.parse();
                                        COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
                                        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                                        PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
                                        //</editor-fold>

                                        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="CRIAR ARQUIVO *.TXT">
                                        FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(outPath + f.getName().replace(".pdf", ".txt")); //Diretório de saida
                                        PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);
                                        //</editor-fold>

                                        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="FECHAR BUFFER DO ARQUIVO *.TXT E DELETAR ARQUIVO *.PDF VERIFICADO">
                                        arq.close();
                                        acesso.close();
                                    }
                                    f.renameTo(new File(outPath, f.getName()));
                                    //</editor-fold>
                                }
                                //</editor-fold>
                            }
                            //</editor-fold>

                        }
                        //</editor-fold>
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); // Tratar a exceção adequadamente.
                    }
                }
            };
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, TEMPO, TEMPO); // Executa a tarefa
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta. Sem vê-lo fica meio complicado deduzir o motivo do problema.

Comment: Editei a pergunta agora

Comment: Rodei a aplicação no NetBeans e na saída ele aparece essa mensagem em vermelho: java.io.IOException: Missing root object specification in trailer.
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseTrailerValuesDynamically(COSParser.java:2094)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.initialParse(PDFParser.java:201)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:249)
 at Embratec.Embratec$1.run(Embratec.java:79)
 at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
 at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505).

Comment: Mas a aplicação está fazendo tudo corretamente

Comment: Boa tarde, Leia esse post que vai te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28199/como-gerar-programa-execut%C3%A1vel-jar-no-netbeans

Comment: Descobri qual era o erro, não sei por qual motivo minha aplicação não havia reconhecido nenhum método principal. Só acrescentei isso e passou a executar perfeitamente

Comment: Seria interessante você publicar uma resposta com a sua solução e marcá-la como resolvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisei ir nas propriedades do meu projeto pois o mesmo estava sem nenhuma classe principal determinada, segue imagem do local onde se altera a informação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]